# Dialog Becomes Transparent Randomly in android

Tags: android, view

I have an issue where popup dialog appears and the background of that dialog appears to be transparent. It does not occur every time and it seems to be appearing only in oreo devices at the moment.

Has anyone experienced this bug? When I google I only find solutions to make a view transparent, not the other way around.

Can anyone help me with this?

This is the expected layout 
[image]

This is the layout that appears sometimes

[image]

Here is the code for the popup

```
public class NotesDialog extends Dialog {
private TextView tv_notes;
private ImageView close;
private String notes;

NotesDialog(Context mContext, String notes) {
    super(mContext);
    this.notes=notes;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.notes_dialog);
    tv_notes = findViewById(R.id.txt_content);
    close = findViewById(R.id.img_close);
    tv_notes.setText(notes);
    tv_notes.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
    close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            dismiss();
        }
    });
    tv_notes.setText(notes);
    tv_notes.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
    close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            dismiss();
        }
    });
 }

}
```

and this is the code that calls the dialog

```
    NotesDialog notesDialog = new NotesDialog(this, notes);
    notesDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        notesDialog.show();
```

and this is the XML file for the dialog

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/white">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/notesHeader"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@color/actionbar">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Notes"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/close"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:id="@+id/img_close"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_below="@+id/notesHeader"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/rlv_body">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txt_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:scrollbars = "vertical"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txt_address"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txt_content"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

 </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: seems like you are using device default themes. Therefore different devices showing dialog differently

Comment: But sometimes it appears as transparent and non-transparent in the same device itself. This is random. I don't know what triggers it.

Comment: show your code and your screenshot currently are from different devices

Comment: question updated with code and screenshots from the same phone